# How to pass the req.user with jwt to main.handlebars to show user is globally logged in?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, handlebars.js

I am using express, node, handlebars, jwt, auth middleware, and NOT using passport (I see this in a lot of the questions about this topic, I can't use that here).

In the navbar of the webpage, I want to have the current logged-in user's information available (via req.user, presumably). There are certain routes that do not require a user to be logged in. Whether that is required or not, I still want the logged-in user's information in the navbar...or if no user is logged in, then nothing in the navbar.

The trouble I have had is when I included `router.get('/home', auth, async (req, res, next) => {}` then that route is not available without being logged in, thus`req.user` is undefined without that. Or is there a way without auth between /home & async?

Seems like the solution is the pass the req.user to main.handlebars somewhere in server.js--that sure would make life easier than passing req.user on each route it is needed.

I am very very new to this, extra effort on what to do will be appreciated. Here is what I have in my auth middleware, if it helps. Thanks!

```
const config = require('config');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const debug = require('debug')('app:auth');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let token = req.cookies.auth_token;
    if (!token) {
      // debug(req.get('Authorization'));
      const authHeader = req.get('Authorization').split(' ');
      if (authHeader.length == 2 && authHeader[0] == 'Bearer') {
        token = authHeader[1];
      }
    }
    if (!token) {
      throw Error('missing token');
    }
    const secret = config.get('auth.secret');
    const payload = jwt.verify(token, secret);
    // debug(payload);
    req.user = payload;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    debug(err.stack);
    res.redirect('/account/login');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Each route you have to pass the variable in the render section eg:

```
    res.render('path and your view filename'), {
           detailUser: req.user
    }
```

In the navbar, you call it eg

`{{detailUser}}`

If there's no req.user details, it won't come up.

I have a shopping cart, and I use session and I pass this variable eg:

```
isCustomer: req.session.customerId
```

and in my header, I have an if statement eg:

```
{{#if isCustomer}}
    conditional logic for if User is a Customer
{{else}}
    conditional logic if not a customer
{{/if}}
```